# trying to get this script to work in Adobe Javascript calculation field, so close

Tags: javascript, if-statement, adobe, acrobat

Im trying to get this script to work in Adobe Javascript calculation field, so close... would appreciate the help. Point of this is to return vehicle trade value multiplied by range provided.

```
var vtv = Number(this.getField("VehicleTradeValue").valueAsString);
  if(vtv > 0)
    vtv *= 2;

  else if(vtv < 6000)
    vtv *= 1.9;

  else if(vtv < 9000)
    vtv *= 1.75;

  else if(vtv < 11000)
    vtv *= 1.5;

  else if(vtv < 12000)
    vtv *= 1.4;

  else if(vtv < 13000)
    vtv *= 1.35;

  else if(vtv < 14000)
    vtv *= 1.3;

  else if(vtv < 17000)
    vtv *= 1.25;

  else if(vtv < 20000)
    vtv *= 1.2;

  else if(vtv < 24000)
    vtv *= 1.15;

  else
    vtv *= 1.1;

  event.value(vtv)
```

Comment: What specifically is going wrong with it? ie what is the current output vs the expected. Also reading up on adobe why are you pulling the value in as a string and not just a .value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the issue is that the code only returns 2x the tvt

if(vtv > 0)
vtv *= 2;

Will return vtv*2 if the value is greater than 0 so the rest of the code doesn't doesn't execute because the first condition was met.

Here are some resources on if/else and maybe you can work through it.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

The gist is that this if statement kinda has a wonky chain. Give it a shot. and work though it logically condition by condition. If you need more assistance let me know.